# linux tar command -t option to show max-depth=1

Tags: linux, shell, tar

may be a tar.gz file has content many filefolder,the filefolder may have a lot of file and filefolder,I want to show the tar.gz file only the first depth.How to write this command.

for example ,I want to show this tar.gz file

[image]

It's only to show auth,help,xa,install.txt,license.txt.release.xt,sqljdbc.jar,sqljdbcr.jar

How to write this command?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://superuser.com ?

Comment: @PaulR: Well, actually, since `tar` itself does not have an appropriate option (AFAICT), the solution *does* involve a bit of bashing... not much, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tar t` itself does not have an option to limit the depth to which the tarball contents are listed, you need to take the full listing and reduce it to what you want.

Since this means `tar` will list the full archive in any case, *it will not be faster than a full listing*.

```
tar tzf <tarball> | sed "s@/.*@@" | sort -u
```

Note that, for all well-behaved tarballs, this will only give *one* entry, of the same name as the tarball.

Real-world example:

```
$ tar tjf gcc-5.2.0.tar.bz2 | sed "s@/.*@@" | sort -u
gcc-5.2.0
```

Tarballs that splatter the extraction directory with files and subfolders are commonly called [tarbombs](http://www.linfo.org/tarbomb.html).